# How to compare group sizes in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Maybe I'm thinking of this in the wrong way but I cannot think of an easy way to do this in pandas. I am trying to get a dataframe that is filtered by the relation between the count values above a setpoint compared to those below it. It is further complicated that it

**Contrived example**: Let's say I have a dataset of people and their test scores over several tests:

```
Person | day | test score |
----------------------------
Bob      1     10
Bob      2     40
Bob      3     45
Mary     1     30
Mary     2     35
Mary     3     45
```

I want to filter this dataframe by the number of test scores >= 40 compared to the total but for each person. Let's say I set the threshold to 50%. So Bob would have 2/3 of test scores but Mary would 1/3 and would be excluded.

My end goal would be to have a groupby object to do means/etc. on those that matched the threshold. So in this case it would look like this:

```
         test score
Person | above_count | total | score mean |
-------------------------------------------
Bob      2             3       31.67
```

I have tried the following but couldn't figure out what to do my groupby object.

```python
df = pd.read_csv("all_data.csv")
gb  = df.groupby('Person')
df2 = df[df['test_score'] >= 40]
gb2 = df2.groupby('Person')

# This would get me the count for each person but how to compare it?
gb.size()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Person': ['Bob'] * 3 + ['Mary'] * 4, 
                   'day': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'test_score': [10, 40, 45, 30, 35, 45, 55]})

>>> df
  Person  day  test_score
0    Bob    1          10
1    Bob    2          40
2    Bob    3          45
3   Mary    1          30
4   Mary    2          35
5   Mary    3          45
6   Mary    4          55
```

In a `groupby` operation, you can pass different functions to perform on the same column via a dictionary.

```
result =  df.groupby('Person').test_score.agg(
              {'total': pd.Series.count, 
               'test_score_above_mean': lambda s: s.ge(40).sum(), 
               'score mean': np.mean})
>>> result
        test_score_above_mean  total  score mean
Person                                          
Bob                         2      3   31.666667
Mary                        2      4   41.250000

>>> result[result.test_score_above_mean.gt(result.total * .5)]
        test_score_above_mean  total  score mean
Person                                          
Bob                         2      3   31.666667
```

Comment: Just curious, is there a reason for using .sum() instead of .count() ?

Comment: `s.ge(40)` will result in a boolean arrary.  If you sum them, you get the number of True instances. If you take the count, you get the number of observations (including the False values).

Answer (score 0):

I think it might make sense to use groupby and aggregations to generate each of your columns as pd.Series, and then paste them together at the end.

```
df = pd.DataFrame([['Bob',1,10],['Bob',2,40],['Bob',3,45],
['Mary',1,30],['Mary',2,35],['Mary',3,45]], columns=
['Person','day', 'test score'])
df_group = df.groupby('Person')
above_count = df_group.apply(lambda x: x[x['test score'] >= 40]['test score'].count())
above_count.name = 'test score above_count'
total_count = df_group['test score'].agg(np.size)
total_count.name = 'total'
test_mean = df_group['test score'].agg(np.mean)
test_mean.name = 'score mean'
results = pd.concat([above_count, total_count, test_mean])
```

Answer (score 0):

Sum and mean can be done with `.agg()` on a groupby object, but the threshold function forces you to do a [flexible apply](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply).

Untested, but something like this should work:

```
df.groupby('Person').apply(lambda x: sum(x > 40), sum(x), mean(x))
```

You could make the lambda function a more complicated, regular function that implements all the criteria/functionality you want.

Comment: I like the conciseness of this method but I could not figure out a way to structure the function to get the result I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easy way of doing this ...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

data = '''Bob      1     10
Bob      2     40
Bob      3     45
Mary     1     30
Mary     2     35
Mary     3     45'''

data = [d.split() for d in data.split('\n')]
data = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'day', 'score'])
data.score = data.score.astype(float)
data['pass']  = (data.score >=40)*1
data['total'] = 1
```

You add two columns for easy computation to data. The result should look like this ...

```
   Name day  score  pass  total
0   Bob   1     10     0      1
1   Bob   2     40     1      1
2   Bob   3     45     1      1
3  Mary   1     30     0      1
4  Mary   2     35     0      1
5  Mary   3     45     1      1
```

Now you summarize the data ...

```
summary = data.groupby('Name').agg(np.sum).reset_index()
summary['mean score']  = summary['score']/summary['total']
summary['pass ratio'] = summary['pass']/summary['total']
print summary
```

The result looks like this ...

```
   Name  score  pass  total  mean score  pass ratio
0   Bob     95     2      3   31.666667    0.666667
1  Mary    110     1      3   36.666667    0.333333
```

Now, you can always filter out the names based on pass ratio ...